# Prove that the group D12 has no element of order 12

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

Is there a way to prove this without checking each element of the group one by one?

Comment: Hint: How many elements does $D_{12}$ have? And why did you completely change the question after it was already answered?

Comment: You should specify whether $D_{12}$ refers to the dihedral group of order $12$ or the dihedral group of order $24$. Both conventions are common. Also, do you know any theorems about the possible orders of subgroups of a finite group?

Comment: Depending on what theorems you know, this video will be helpful https://youtube.com/watch?v=Vppbdf-qtGU

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** If $D_{12}$ would have an element of order $12$, it would be cyclic, hence abelian

Comment: Although useful at the time... the OP has unfortunately changed the question now.  *sigh*

Comment: Ya that's my bad,  I'm sorry about that.

Comment: @one over pie Its better if the question has to be rolled back